# Summing string elements in an array using `Array#sum`

Tags: ruby

In the following array of Integer objects, `Array#sum` sums the elements:

```
[1, 2].sum #=> 3
```

For an array of strings, I was expecting `sum` to return the total concatenation (`'12'` in this case) but am getting an error:

```
['1', '2'].sum
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#        4: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
#        3: from (irb):46
#        2: from (irb):46:in `sum'
#        1: from (irb):46:in `+'
#TypeError (String can't be coerced into Integer)
```

How can I get `['1', '2'].sum` to return `'12'`, if it is even possible?

Comment: ['1', '2'].join => '12'

Comment: @Ashik thanks that is the idiomatic approach I agree. I just wanted to see how it could be done with `sum`.

Comment: if by using sum you meant using the + operator on string you could do for fun : `['1','2','3'].inject(:+)` => `"123"`

Comment: @Alexis Thanks, interesting to note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array#sum` defines a single parameter which by default is `0`. Your first snippet is equivalent to:

```
[1, 2].sum(0) #=> 3
```

Your second snippet is equivalent to:

```
['1', '2'].sum(0)
```

As indicated by the error message, you end up trying to add the string `'1'` to the integer `0` etc, which Ruby won't allow (no type coercion here). So in order to make this work, define an empty string as the argument:

```
['1', '2'].sum('') #=> "12"
```

Now you're doing `'' + '1' + '2'` etc. See [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) for more info, where it's also noted that `join` would be faster than `sum` when summing an array of strings. Also `join` is way more idiomatic.

Comment: Anyone (since the OP hasn't) got any ideas as to why this was downvoted? Seems like the same voter (within seconds) downvoted my question too.